# How to reverse rows of a data.frame or data.table in R

Tags: r

How can I reverse the order of a row so that the last value becomes the second value, second-to-last value becomes the third value, etc.? The first column (`ID`) should stay the in the same place. Missing values in the rows shouldn't be included in the reversal.

Taking the last row as an example, the last value "67" gets moved to the last row of the second column (one). The second-to-last value "68" gets moved to the last row of the third column (two).

Original:

```
structure(list(ID = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", 
"i", "j", "k", "l"), one = c(1, 2, 4, 7, 11, 16, 22, 29, 37, 
46, 56, 67), two = c(NA, 3, 5, 8, 12, 17, 23, 30, 38, 47, 57, 
68), three = c(NA, NA, 6, 9, 13, 18, 24, 31, 39, 48, 58, 69), 
    four = c(NA, NA, NA, 10, 14, 19, 25, 32, 40, 49, 59, 70), 
    five = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 15, 20, 26, 33, 41, 50, 60, 71), 
    six = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 21, 27, 34, 42, 51, 61, 72), 
    seven = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 28, 35, 43, 52, 62, 73), 
    eight = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 36, 44, 53, 63, 74), 
    nine = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 45, 54, 64, 75), 
    ten = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 55, 65, 76), 
    eleven = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 66, 77
    ), twelve = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    78)), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Outcome:

```
structure(list(ID = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", 
"i", "j", "k", "l"), one = c(1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, 
55, 66, 78), two = c(NA, 2, 5, 9, 14, 20, 27, 35, 44, 54, 65, 
77), three = c(NA, NA, 4, 8, 13, 19, 26, 34, 43, 53, 64, 76), 
    four = c(NA, NA, NA, 7, 12, 18, 25, 33, 42, 52, 63, 75), 
    five = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 11, 17, 24, 32, 41, 51, 62, 74), 
    six = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 16, 23, 31, 40, 50, 61, 73), 
    seven = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 22, 30, 39, 49, 60, 72), 
    eight = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 29, 38, 48, 59, 71), 
    nine = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 37, 47, 58, 70), 
    ten = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 46, 57, 69), 
    eleven = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 56, 68
    ), twelve = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    67)), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `apply` row-wise and reverse the non-NA values in each row.

```
df[-1] <- t(apply(df[-1], 1, function(x) {x[!is.na(x)] <- rev(x[!is.na(x)]);x}))
```

Comment: Will this work even if the df is not structured the same as the example (i.e., missingness varies between rows)?

Comment: This will reverse values only at non-NA places. `NA` values remain as it is. See this example `x <- c(2, 3, NA, 1, 4, NA, 5)` and `x[!is.na(x)] <- rev(x[!is.na(x)])`

Comment: What is the semicolon?

Comment: Using semicolon we can add number of statements in the same line.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df1 %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = -ID) %>% 
    group_by(ID) %>%
    mutate(value = replace(value, !is.na(value), rev(value[!is.na(value)]))) %>% 
    ungroup %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value)
# A tibble: 12 x 13
#   ID      one   two three  four  five   six seven eight  nine   ten eleven twelve
#   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1 a         1    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA     NA
# 2 b         3     2    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA     NA
# 3 c         6     5     4    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA     NA
# 4 d        10     9     8     7    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA     NA
# 5 e        15    14    13    12    11    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA     NA
# 6 f        21    20    19    18    17    16    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA     NA
# 7 g        28    27    26    25    24    23    22    NA    NA    NA     NA     NA
# 8 h        36    35    34    33    32    31    30    29    NA    NA     NA     NA
# 9 i        45    44    43    42    41    40    39    38    37    NA     NA     NA
#10 j        55    54    53    52    51    50    49    48    47    46     NA     NA
#11 k        66    65    64    63    62    61    60    59    58    57     56     NA
#12 l        78    77    76    75    74    73    72    71    70    69     68     67
```